Web Scraping beautifoul soap
quisiera saber si alguien me puede dar una mano, estoy queriendo hacer scraping de paginas https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/ o https://www.masonline.com.ar/
El problema es que cuando inspecciono la misma, obtengo un DOM distinto al que me obtiene el soap..
Alguien me podria decir si esta pagina es dinamica o como podria hacer scraping de los productos que se encuentran en esas paginas?
Necesito obtener los nombres de los productos listados en la pagina.
El codigo lo dejo debajo y la imagen corresponde a lo que me muestra al inspeccionar la el html.


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
     

# Versiones
import bs4 # Solo para el chequeo
print("Versión de BeautifulSoup:",bs4.__version__)
print("Versión de requests:", requests.__version__)
     
# Empezamos el scraping

# 1. Obtener el HTML
URL_BASE = 'https://www.masonline.com.ar/'
pedido_obtenido = requests.get(URL_BASE)
html_obtenido = pedido_obtenido.text

# 2. "Parsear" ese HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_obtenido, "html.parser")
with open('resultado.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as archivo:
    archivo.write(str(soup))
#El método find()

#Nos permite quedarnos con la información asociada a una etiqueta de HTML

primer_h2 = soup.find('h2')
print(primer_h2.text)

# equivalente a:
# print(soup.h2.text)
   

#El método find_all()

#Busca TODOS los elementos de la página con esa etiqueta y devuelve una "lista" que los contiene (en realidad devuelve un objeto de la clase bs4.element.ResultSet).

h2_todos = soup.find_all('h2')
     
# get_text() pero sacando espacios en blanco
for seccion in h2_todos:
  print(seccion.get_text(strip=True))
     

h3_element = soup.find('div', class_='valtech-gdn-product-summary-status-0-x-container')
print(h3_element)


# Clase
divs = soup.find_all('span', class_='vtex-product-summary-2-x-productBrand')
print(divs)
divs2 = soup.select('div.vtex-product-summary-2-x-nameContainer')
print(divs2)
for div in divs:
  print(div)
  print(" ")
     

input("Presiona Enter para salir...")





Hola Cesar, bienvenido, los códigos como texto, no imagenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, para evitar recibir votos negativos y/o el cierre de la misma.
